# my list is not appearing using meteorjs

Tags: meteor

Hy guys i made this code:

--> places_list.html

```
<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Testing with places</h1>
  {{> places_list}}
</body>
<template name="places_list">
  {{#each places}}
  {{ name}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
enter code here
```

--> places_list.js

```
Places = new Meteor.Collection('placesNew');


if(Meteor.is_client){
  Template.places_list.places = function(){
    return Places.find({},{sort:{name: 1}});
  }

}
```

It appears to be ok, but when  i go to the browser to insert some data like this:

```
Places.insert({name: "New York"});
```

Nothing change... i thought that it was some thing wrong with mongo, but if i go to the browser and try that:

```
Places.find({},{sort{name: 1}});
```

I can see the data i've inputed...where is my mistake? what's wrong with this small and disturbing code?....

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your places_list.js you should have **isClient** instead of is_client.